# Mercurial - getting changes from other repository

Tags: mercurial

We have a Mercurial repository on BitBucket. This repository is used by a bunch of people.

Now I have another local repository which is a super-set of the BitBucket repo. What I want to do is work in my repo and get changes from the other repo whenever the others commit and push. I do not want to get the history of those other files just the last revision.

What is the best way to do that?

At the moment, I have cloned the other repository and I pull changes from that one into mine. That works but my issue is that whenever I get a change I have to do a huge merge in order to fix my repository. Is there another way to just get changes from the other repository and put them in my branch? I don't care about getting the history of those files. I could just copy and paste them in my repo but I'd like to be able to merge changes whenever possible which is not possible just by overwriting the updated files by copy-pasting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the other repository as a [subrepository](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository) into yours.

This is not exactly what you requested, since you said that you don't want the history of the other repository, only the last revision.
But as you already noticed yourself, everything else that you tried (pulling the other repository into yours, copying files manually, ...) is a hassle.
With subrepositories, you can just update the subrepository to get the changes tht the others made.

Comment: Ok I'll give it a shot and I will come back to you. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Ok so is there a way to add a subrepository so that when I update it, it affects the same files as the parent repo? For example say I have a file A.txt in the main repo. If a user changes file A in the subrepo and I pull that change it affects file A.txt in the main repo. Can I do that?